# Execute multiple python files using a single main

Tags: python

I have multiple python files, each with different classes and methods in it. I want to execute all those files with a main function I have separately outside all of them.

For example:

I have three files say one.py, two.py, three.py

I have no main method in any of them, but when I execute them then I want them to pass through the main function that I have separately. Is this possible, how?

Thanks.

Comment: can you create a new file like a driver.py and have it import and execute the correct code? or were you interested in something more dynamic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use them as modules and import them into your script containing main.

```
import one
import two
import three

if __name__ == '__main__':
    one.foo()
    two.bar()
    three.baz()
```

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean you want to import them?

```
import one
import two
import three

result = one.func()
instance = two.YourClass()
something = three.func()
```

Note that there is no "main method" in python (perhaps you've been using JAVA?).  When you say `python thisfile.py`, python executes all of the code in "thisfile.py".  One neat little trick that we use is that each "module" has an attribute "**name**".  the script invoked directly (e.g. `thisfile.py`) gets assigned the name `"__main__"`.  That allows you to separate the portion of a module which is meant to be a script, and the portion which is meant to be reused elsewhere.  A common use case for this is testing:

```
#file: thisfile.py
def func():
   return 1,2,3

if __name__ == "__main__":
   if func() != (1,2,3):
      print "Error with func"
   else:
      print "func checks out OK"
```

Now if I run this as `python thisfile.py`, it will print `func checks out OK`, but if I import it in another file, e.g:

```
#anotherfile.py
import thisfile
```

and then I run that file via `python anotherfile.py`, nothing will get printed.

Comment: Note this will be one after the other.

Comment: I'd imagine that the running part would be in the `if '__name__'...` section of each module...

Comment: @PierreGM -- Probably.  but I think the OP might have some confusion about what `if __name__ == '__main__':` actually means ...

Comment: @PierreGM -- Updated with an explanation of `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file that imports these files and run that file.

Answer (score 1):

As previous answers suggest, if you simply need to re-use the functionality do an import.

However, if you do not know the file names in advance, you would need to use a slightly different import construct. For a file called `one.py` located in the same directory, use:

Contents of the one.py:

```
print "test"
def print_a():
    print "aa"
```

Your main file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    imp = __import__("one")
    print dir(imp)
```

Prints out test and also gives information about the methods contained in the imported file.